# Microsoft workdflow custom connector

Tags: asp.net, azure, connector, power-automate

I am trying to develop a simple customer connector for my website on microsoft flow and so far I can't see how to use a web API that is hosted on my website every article tutorial I am coming by require APIs to be hosted on Azure, also an Azure account is a prerequisite .. is it true Only azure APIs to be used for custom connectors ?

Answer (score 1):

Azure is not a prerequisite for Custom Connector. I agree that most of the tutorials talk about connecting Azure hosted apps.

Microsoft flow currently supports creating custom connector with Swagger API output or postman exported data. I created a Postman collection with the API and gave the exported data as input to Microsoft flow for creating the connector.

Detailed Tutorial is available here 
https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/postman-collection/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, I have configured a custom connector for testing to go against this test / mock API

`POST -> https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`

In the connector test it keep on hitting this URL:

`https://msmanaged-na.azure-apim.net/apim/zoom.2dtest.2d002.5f43ed1d930148619c.5f4fd64f4beaca2b60/51136e9557bf4e128e0d7552ff624ebd/posts`

I have never configure it to go there. No document explains how or why this would happen.