# How do I Create a Custom Connector in Microsoft Flow with the correct request URL?

Tags: power-automate, clio-api

I am attempting to create a custom connector for the Clio API (https://app.clio.com/api/v4/documentation). I was able to successfully authenticate and access the API in Postman, testing out quite a few different types of requests with good results.

Then I exported the collection to a Postman file and imported it into a new custom connector in my MS Flow account as instructed at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-postman-collection. As part of that process, I entered the following settings:

Scheme: `HTTPS`

host: `app.clio.com`

Base URL: `/`

Within the custom connector requests, all the definitions looked acceptable, except that instead of having the fully qualified request URL, they did not include `https://app.clio.com`.

For example, one request should use the following address:

`https://app.clio.com/api/v4/contacts.json`

The field in MS Flow, where URL should be entered, is grayed out and only includes `/api/v4/contacts.json` and looks like this:
[image: screenshot from MS Flow definition for this API request]

The grayed out field cannot be typed in. Instead, I have clicked "Import from sample," which leads to a window where I can type in the fully qualified URL. After I do that and click the "import" button, the window still lists the partial URL as shown above.

At first I thought that was intentional, since I had entered the host elsewhere for the connector, and I thought that Flow would put them together to send the request to the right URL. But it did not: when I tested the operation, I got a 404 error:

```
    {
  "error": "{\r\n  \"code\": 404,\r\n  \"message\": \"Unable to match incoming request to an operation.\",\r\n  \"source\": \"msmanaged-na.azure-apim.net\",\r\n  \"path\": \"\",\r\n  \"clientRequestId\": \"500779d5-356d-4c79-bf96-caf2-f5bc2919\"\r\n}"
}
```

When I looked at the request, this is the URL:

```
https://msmanaged-na.azure-apim.net/apim/clio2.5fb03ce8462066f352.5fdeb6bc35b813689d/92053762-68ce-4c1d-9085-0785-0fd98c3b/api/v4/contacts.json?type=Person
```

So obviously Flow is not using the correct request URL, and I cannot figure out how to enter the fully qualified request URL. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

I found another comment where someone else is having the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813209/7191369 so I'm not the only one. Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit:**

After some additional searching, the address in the request (with `https://msmanaged-na.azure-apim.net`) is the required redirect URL for the proxy per this post: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/custom-api-with-authentication/, and is used when processing OAuth. But the crappy part of this is that I can't see the request URL so I can't troubleshoot. Is there any way to see what request the proxy server is sending out to the Clio API?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this? I'm trying to integrate a service into Flow and am having the same issue. Ironically, it works correctly in Logic Apps, but not Flow. In my case, I have my own OpenAPI definition and the API is an anonymous endpoint authenticated by a license key passed in as a header value. Despite having no required authentication (ie OAuth), requests are still being sent from the msmanaged-na.azure-apim.net/apim endpoints with a bearer token. Flow certainly seems to be injecting something unwanted into the requests, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Comment: See my edit--the msmanaged-na.azure-apim.net/apim endpoints are the proxy. I was able to get it working by going through the "import from sample" menu and then carefully making sure the parameters in the request were correct.

Comment: Ironically, my issue was just being caused by a delay when editing or creating a connector. A delay of up to 5 minutes is common once you've updated or created a connector. Waiting 5 minutes between when creating/updating and trying to consume solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since this question was posted, but let me give you a suggestion to include the **/api/v4** part of the URL inside the **Base URL** property of the Flow. This way all your endpoints will use the specified version and you will not have to define them one by one in each request.

Except if you intentionally want to use different versions across the requests :) Anyways, I'm glad that you've been able to resolve the issue.